# How can I convert hex number to integers and strings in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hex

Given the example of an array like this:

```
idx = [ 0xe, 0x3,  0x6, 0x8, 0x2 ]
```

I want to get an integer and string representation of each of the specified items in Objective C. I have mocked up a ruby example which works perfectly:

```
0xe gives 14 when i run 0xe.to_i and "e" when i run to_i(base=16)
0x3 gives 3 when i run 0x3.to_i and gives 3 when i run to_i(base=16)
```

How can I achieve this in Objective C?

Comment: Are these non-localized numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the decimal and hexadecimal equivalents, you would do:

```
int number = 0xe; // or 0x3, 0x6, 0x8, 0x2

NSString * decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
NSString * hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", number];
```

Comment: Thanks, Ok that's a bit helpfull. But can I store 0xe in NSNumber? I cannot assign it to a int as i want to store this stuff in NSArray as you can't use standard C types in it (mutable or not)

Comment: NSNumber can wrap any of the primitive numeric types. Of course, once you're making string representations of the numbers, 
you could store the strings in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an NSString you can just use the methods in that class, like intValue or longValue or floatValue