# How to convert hexadecimal string to decimal?

Tags: objective-c, ios, decimal, hex

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how I can convert hexadecimal letters within an `NSString`, e.g. `@"50A6C2"`, to decimals using Objective-C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934790/how-can-i-convert-hex-number-to-integers-and-strings-in-objective-c) post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the methods `scanHexInt:` or `scanHexLongLong:`. Another possibility is to get the C string from the NSString and use C-style functions such as [`strtol`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/strtol.3.html) (with base 16).

Comment: Is it possible to convert rgb to hex using objective-c?