# How to convert decimal into octal in objective c

Tags: objective-c, hex, octal

just like my question, How can i convert decimal into octal in objective c?
can somebody help me? it's make me dizy

Comment: What are you trying to do ? converting strings ?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to converting strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934790/how-can-i-convert-hex-number-to-integers-and-strings-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a new `NSString` object using the right format specifier.

Like :

```
int i = 9;
NSString *octalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%o", i]; // %O works too.
```

This will create an autoreleased `NSString` object containing octal string representation of `i`. In case you start from a `NSString` 
containing a decimal number representation, you should first retrieve the number using :

```
int i = [myDecimalNumberAsAString intValue];
```

Here is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) to the format specifiers reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a NSString for example hold a string like '0xfff9f4'. How can I cover it to a octal number?

Answer (score 0):

Since Objective C is a superset of C you can just use C functions such as [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), e.g.

```
char s[32];
int n = 42;
sprintf(s, "%o", n);
```

Comment: @Risma: if you click on the word `sprintf` in the answer above you will find that it is a link which takes you to the full documentation for the sprintf C library function.