# Converting a octal String to Decimal in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, base-conversion

I trying to do conversions between Binary, Octal, Decimal and Hexadecimal in Objective-C.
I had problems converting Octal to Decimal.

I have tried the following:

```
NSString *decString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 077];
```

It works fine, returning 63 as expected, but my Octal value is a NSString. How can I tell the computer that it is a Octal;

I know there is a method called "scanHexInt:" which I used to convert Hexadecimal to decimal, but it seems there is no scanOctInt...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look over there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647787/how-to-convert-decimal-into-octal-in-objective-c

Comment: @rdurand But how does this help to convert an octal NSString into an int?

Comment: @nullp01nter Woops, my bad, I read incorrectly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest solution is probably:

```
long result = strtol(input.UTF8String, NULL, 8);
```

or

```
long long result = strtoll(input.UTF8String, NULL, 8);
```

Comment: I like this answer even better than mine XD +1

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But there is a little problem, if the value is larger than 10,000,000,000, it went wrong. I've already defined result as unsigned long long int.

Answer (score 3):

Define a category on NSString (put this on top of any of your source code modules or into a new .m/.h file pair, @interface goes into .h, @implementation into .m):

```
@interface NSString (NSStringWithOctal)
-(int)octalIntValue;
@end

@implementation NSString (NSStringWithOctal)
-(int)octalIntValue
{
    int iResult = 0, iBase = 1;
    char c;

    for(int i=(int)[self length]-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if((c<'0')||(c>'7')) return 0;
        iResult += (c - '0') * iBase;
        iBase *= 8; 
    }
    return iResult;
}
@end
```

Use it like that:

```
NSString *s = @"77";
int i = [s octalIntValue];
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

The method returns an integer representing the octal value in the string. It returns 0, if the string is not an octal number. Leading zeroes are allowed, but not necessary.

Comment: Well... yes :) But at least it is educational.

Comment: It works, but it dosen't work well in a for circulation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to drop down to C, you can use `sscanf`

```
int oct;
sscanf( [yourString UTF8String], "%o", &oct );
```