# How can i convert NSString to uint8_t array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSString like so: 850210

How can i convert it to uint8_t data[]={0x85,0x02,0x10};

Could someone please help me out with this??

BR,
Suppi

Comment: This question might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values

Comment: This is a duplicate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782327/converting-nsstring-into-uint8-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
static NSString * const hexString = @"850210";

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    uint8_t         data[3]={0};
    const char      * theUniChar = hexString.UTF8String;

    for( int i = 0, c = (int)strlen(theUniChar)/2; i < c && i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data); i++ )
    {
        int     theNum = 0;
        sscanf( theUniChar + 2*i, "%2x", &theNum );
        data[i] = theNum;
    }

    printf( "{%x,%x,%x}\n", data[0],data[1],data[2] );


    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot this worked, but off course if you want leading zeros i used "%02X" and  theNum & 0xFF; to convert to back to hex.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the string and start by checking for strings of length < 3. If it is just simply call intValue on the NSString itself and you have your first and only byte.

If it's larger than or equal to three start by reading in three numbers and checking if that is larger than 255. If it is re-read in the two bytes and check what value they have and that's a byte. If it's not then take the three first numbers and that's a byte.

Repeat this process on the remaining string that you have (a string created by disregarding the numbers you have already read in).

Good luck :)

---

I was assuming that string was in decimal format. If that's hex then simply read in two numbers at a time. And use this question to help you: [How can I convert hex number to integers and strings in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934790/how-can-i-convert-hex-number-to-integers-and-strings-in-objective-c)

---

Second edit:

I have not tested this but you if there are any errors they should be easy to fix:

```
NSString *hexString = @"8510A0";
uint8_t *result = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * ([hexString length] / 2));
for(int i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2) {
    NSRange range = { i, 2 };
    NSString *subString = [hexString subStringWithRange:range];
    unsigned value;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:subString] scanHexInt:&value];
    result[i / 2] = (uint8_t)value;
}
// result now contains what you want
free(result)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur suggestion, if i can read them two at a time, how do i put it in uint8_t array?? how can i convert string to uint8_t#

Comment: Hi, until value it is correct, but the result is wrong. I am printing it as %c i don't get the required result. Wats wrong??

Comment: Have you debugged it to check what's in result? I think you might have to cast the index into result like this: (int)(i / 2) and then don't forget to free(result) when you're done. And printing it as %c will print the ascii character with that particular code.... (also the string I put there in my example is different to yours)

Comment: yeah i checked the result, it remains 85 all the time and for value when its A0 it shows as 0.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry I now realise my mistake. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I am trying to write a message as uint8_t array to a bluetooth device using BTStack. when i give the message like this for ex uint8_t data[]={0x85,0x02,0x10}; it works fine, but if i use the above code its doesnt work. But the result from the above code seems to be correct.